# Python: Increasing floating point precision produces incorrect results?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that recursively calculates the nth order derivate of a function at a given point `x`. I have used the simple definition of a derivative:

```
f'(x) =  f(x + h) - f(x)
         ---------------
                h
lim h -> 0
```

```
def deriv(f, x, n=1, h=1e-4):
    if n == 0:  # 0th order deriv is the function itself (base case)
        return f(x)
    return (deriv(f, x+h, n-1, h) - deriv(f, x, n-1, h))/h

f = lambda x: x**3
print("x\tf(x)\tf'(x)\tf''(x)\tf'''(x)")
for x in range(5, 10):
    print(x, f(x), deriv(f, x), deriv(f, x, 2), deriv(f, x, 3), sep='\t')
```

For `h = 1e-4`, I got the following results:

```
x       f(x)    f'(x)   f''(x)  f'''(x)
5       125     75.00150000979033       30.00060075919464       5.982769835100044
6       216     108.00180000984483      36.00059699238045       6.053824108676054
7       343     147.00210000967218      42.00060175207909       5.968558980384842
8       512     192.0024000094145       48.00060651177773       5.7980287238024175
9       729     243.00270000935598      54.0005999027926        6.02540239924565
```

I am focusing on the last column: the third derivative of `x^3` should be `6` and the values are pretty much close to `6`! Now I though making `h` smaller would lead to more accurate results so I changed it to `1e-5`, but   the results are incorrect:

```
x       f(x)    f'(x)   f''(x)  f'''(x)
5       125     75.00014999664018       30.000251172168642      -28.421709430404004
6       216     108.00017999486043      36.000358250021236      -56.84341886080801
7       343     147.0002099949852       41.99989689368522       56.84341886080801
8       512     192.0002399970144       47.9997197544435        0.0
9       729     243.00026999526378      53.998974181013175      227.37367544323203
```

The first two columns seem to be alright. I think the issue is with floating point inaccuracy but I cannot decide exactly what is going wrong and what the threshold is beyond which the results will be inaccurate.

Comment: How does your `deriv()` function work. I mean specifically on the `return` line there is something where one value is subtracted from another. It looks like you should get `0.0`

Comment: sorry that's a typo, I'll fix it.

Comment: Its definitely a precision thing. Your code works down to: `5e-5`, but if you have: `for x in range(19, 29):` you need: `5e-4`

Comment: Thanks. Is there any workaround for this kind of situation?

Comment: Naive numerical differentiation is numerically unstable, and you are iterating it. The solution is to use a more stable algorithm. Consult a text in numerical analysis.